# How to find the "Assignment " tab on EasyChair

Tags: easychair

I am using EasyChair and I saw that in some tutorials they have the assignment tab in the main menu, but in my case there is none, how can I add it or find it?

Answer (score 5):

Go to Administration -> Config

"Is assignment of submitted papers to the program committee enabled?" --> Yes.

Should work.